# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Preventing Direct Access to Custom Error Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, custom-error-pages

[image]

It won't let me submit with the codes above, had to take a screenshot.
As It can be seen above, I'm using customError pages to handle appropriate errors. Everything works as expected, for instance when a user gets an unhandled exception, on my local the URL is changing as expected :
`http://localhost/SystemAdministration/Error`

However, I don't want users to access this page by typing the url to their browser. Whats the best way to restrict direct access to these error pages and only show them when the related error has occured?
Thanks

Comment: You could create an `ActionFilter` that checks the status code for something other than 200. If it's 200, then redirect somewhere else (homepage perhaps?). Decorate your error page action(s) with this newly created filter.

Comment: Hello, It looks like a nice suggestion however couldnt get it work. Attached a new custom ActionFilter to my "NotFound" action and on it's onActionExecuting method, my  filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode returns 200. I gotta somehow get the statusCode prior to requesting the "NotFound" action, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action filter to do that. It's explained in [ASP.NET MVC Custom Action Filter To Restrict Direct Access To Action Method](http://www.jlum.ws/post/2013/12/17/aspnet-mvc-custom-action-filter-to-restrict-direct-access-to-action-method). Hope this helps